# camera module isn't getting detected

Tags: hardware

Lately, I have been having some problems with my pi camera it used to work but no it isn't it is Raspberry pi camera 1.3v OV5647.
the pi is falling to detect it.

```
supported=1 detected=0, libcamera interfaces=1
```

Here are some more of the errors:

```
raspistill -o test.jpg
```

```
mmal: Cannot read camera info, keeping the defaults for OV5647
mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1:ENOMEM)
mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1)
mmal: Failed to create camera component
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Camera is not detected. Please check carefully the camera module is installed correctly
sudo libcamera-hello
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
Made X/EGL preview window
[0:01:18.159614751] [1783]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:297 libcamera v0.0.5+83-bde9b04f
[0:01:18.365258342] [1804]  INFO RPI vc4.cpp:437 Registered camera /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/ov5647@36 to Unicam device /dev/media3 and ISP device /dev/media0
[0:01:18.365477637] [1804]  INFO RPI pipeline_base.cpp:1101 Using configuration file '/usr/share/libcamera/pipeline/rpi/vc4/rpi_apps.yaml'
[0:01:18.372875348] [1783]  INFO Camera camera.cpp:1033 configuring streams: (0) 1296x972-YUV420
[0:01:18.374437191] [1804]  INFO RPI vc4.cpp:565 Sensor: /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/ov5647@36 - Selected sensor format: 1296x972-SGBRG10_1X10 - Selected unicam format: 1296x972-pGAA
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  failed to import fd 19
Aborted
```

here is what I tried to do

1. update the firmware
2. check the connection between the pi and the camera with a multimeter
3. update the pi
4. Make `GPU-mem=256`
5. `camera_auto_detect = 1`
6. check the ribbon cable
7. check if there is a faulty resistor on the camera module itself
8. Start_x=0

I couldn't find the problem.

Comment: You can't use the old raspixxx aps on Bookworm. You need to use the new camera stack (libcamera). See Pi docs

Answer (score 0):

- check whether you have connected the camera module properly with the pi.
- check the red light on the camera module is visible.

Comment: it is connected properly and the LED lights up when the pi first turn on